# SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement running sql function from jdbc

Tags: oracle, jdbc, sql-function

I have below java code:

```
void insertRatings(String Rname , String uName ,BigDecimal rating , String rDate) throws SQLException, ParseException
    {
        CallableStatement cs = conn.prepareCall("? = call insertRating(?,?,?,?) ");

        cs.registerOutParameter(1, Types.INTEGER);
        cs.setString(2, Rname);
        cs.setString(3, uName);
        cs.setBigDecimal(4, rating);
        cs.setDate(5,new Date(new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse(rDate).getTime()));


        cs.executeQuery();

        System.out.println("Output recived from fucntion :: "+cs.getInt(1));

    }
```

And SQL function is:

```
create or replace function insertRating(Rname varchar2(100),uName varchar2(100),rating Number,
rDate Date) return Integer is
```

The SQL function works as expected. However, when I run the java code I get the below error for `cs.executeQuery();`

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement
```

What did I miss?

Comment: Why not take a look at the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/jjdbc/JDBC-getting-started.html#GUID-98F62472-1415-4099-A6B6-7C13C6AEC040)?

Answer (score 2):

I got the solution:

```
CallableStatement cs = conn.prepareCall(" { ? = call insertRating(?,?,?,?) }");
```

'{}' is what I was missing.

I hope it will someone.